# Interpolation undefined on domain

Tags: interpolation

I have made an interpolation of two variables of a fairly large set of numbers imported from a file (4 million lines in an .m file written out with C++).

The ranges of the two parameters is 0 to 2.5 and 0 to 60, respectively, so I am confused why the interpolation for certain ranges inside `0:2.5, 0:60` , seen most clearly when plotting.

When evaluating in one of these undefined ranges, for example `0.2, 0.2` it takes many seconds before finally outputting something like this.

```
0.030098` + 
0.005752199999999999` (1.8894271781617253` - 
0.009955999999999993` (22.098356216511277` + 
   0.0214602` (-55.4176617318362` - 
      0.025663999999999992` (-1495.3986641465997` + 
         0.03716810000000001` (10148.485672332376` - 
            0.04137199999999999` (61777.19935813235` + 
               0.0528761` (-818590.1061571125` - 
                0.05707999999999999` (-15.915482422145436` \
(818590.1061571125` - 
                12.73234946224922` (-10343.382090047433` - 
                21.220654487425698` (-7724.724645111078` - 
                10.61029347010709` (865.1929296352522` - 
                31.83091418385536` (21.333461835452677` - 
                9.094538638602133` (-15.74708850390108` - 
                63.66182836771069` (-1.7906312792105215` - 
                7.9577222134245185` (-5.197116` + 
                2.53974` e))))))))))))))))
```

It seems that `e` is undefined, so why would Mathematica use it automatically?

If I manually set `e = E`, then I can evaluate the above lines, but the function is still unwilling to be plotted on some ranges (takes several minutes of "running" after which is stops with `$Aborted` message).

Could it be that I should simply not use `Interpolation` for files that big?

Comment: Found out it was the way that the .m file was being written. It writes scientific as `5e-5` for instance, whereas Mathematica would write `5*^-5` so the error was on my part.
Not sure if the post should be deleted then?

Comment: `Import[]` can handle exponential notation: `ImportString["2e-5,3e-4\n0.4,0.1", "CSV"]`.

Comment: @KasparH, you could self answer your question or delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out it was the way that the .m file was being written. It writes scientific as `5e-5` for instance, whereas Mathematica would write `5*^-5` so the error was on my part. Posted anyway to potentially help other clueless people like me.